# Hibernate / JPA using criteria as annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Does anybody know if it's possible to impose criteria on an object property via annotations.  This would be similar to the @Where clause, however the attribute that I need to filter by is not actually on the table the SELECT is performed on since it is mappedBy.

Hopefully this example will illustrate:

```
public class Container {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "container")
  private List<Item> items;

  //getter & setter ...

}

public class Item {

  @ManyToOne
  private Container container;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "item")
  private User user;

  //getter & setter ...

}

public class User {

  @OneToOne
  private Item item;

  //getter & setter ...

}
```

I would like to fetch a `Container` where there is no `User` associated.  If the `user` attribute was really on the `Item` table it should be possible to use @Where:

```
public class Container {

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "container")
  @Where(clause = "user is null")
  private List<Item> items;

  //getter & setter ...

}
```

But since it is mappedBy is there a way of doing this?  The join on these tables is obviously already performed in the SQL.  Maybe there is a way of referencing the `user` attribute e.g. HQL?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: You have a small error: in `Container` items is a `OneToMany`, not a `OneToOne`.

Answer (score 0):

In `HQL`:

```
select item.container from item i where i.user is null
```

**Container.java**

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "findContainerWithNoUser",
    query = "select item.container from item i where i.user is null"
    )
})
@Entity
public class Container {

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "container")
  private List<Item> items;

  //getter & setter ...

}
```

Comment: This is interesting, thank you.  I'm trying to get to a point where I can do a simple dao.load(containerId) and this query be run to fetch the Container object.  Is it possible to have this behaviour?